# Arguments for Functional Programming

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, f#

I've recently been learning F# for fun (I'm a VB.NET/C# dev), and I really like some of what it has to offer. Theoretically that is. But I'm having trouble thinking up of scenarios where I would choose to code in F# rather than in C#. Any ideas?

Comment: `F#` is not fully representative of functional programming. Try `Clojure` instead.

Comment: I don't know F#, but I use Haskell whenever I want my mind blown. Worked every time so far ;)

Comment: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Are-We-There-Yet-Rich-Hickey is a great video on this topic (OO vs. Functional)

Comment: A dynamic functional language? You can have as many as you want. :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A few arguments for pure functional programming:

- It's easier to divide tasks for today's multi-core systems
- It's easier to prove your program is correct
- Functional composition can be amazing, terse, and powerful

For a full treatment, see [Why Functional Programming Matters](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/Papers/whyfp.pdf) and [Why Why Functional Programming Matters Matters](http://weblog.raganwald.com/2007/03/why-why-functional-programming-matters.html).

Answer (score 7):

> I'm having trouble thinking up of scenarios where I would choose to code in F# rather than in C#. Any ideas?

From [here](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2012/02/benefits-of-f.html):

Asynchronous servers

- Asynchronous workflows for the asynchronous IO.
- Mailbox processor for the thread-safe message passing.
- Union types for server state and message catalogue.
- Pattern matching and tail recursion for the state machines.

Metaprogramming (e.g. parsing)

- Parser generators like fslex and fsyacc.
- Parser combinators like FParsec.
- Active patterns for elegant hand-rolled parsers.
- Algebraic datatypes to represent parse trees.
- Pattern matching to manipulate trees, e.g. apply optimization stages.
- Reflection for run-time generation of fast code.

Technical computing

- Higher-order functions for elegant and fast algorithmic code.
- Algebraic datatypes and pattern matching for symbolic manipulation.
- Interoperability for wealth of .NET libraries.
- Interactivity using F# interactive.
- Computation expressions for massaging data.
- Units of measure for improved correctness.

GUI applications

- Model as asynchronous message passing between user interface code and application logic code.
- Higher-order functions let you define user interfaces declaratively.

Logic programming

- Persistent collections for easy backtracking.
- Tail calls for reliability.
- Automatic generalization for easy generic programming.

Testing

- Run unit tests interactively.
- BDD means writing an interpreter.
- Good scripting language for writing test harnesses and visualizing results.

Performance

- `inline` for cost-free higher-order abstraction.
- Tail calls for fast state machines.
- Purely functional data structures for low latency.
- Metaprogramming for generation of optimized code.

Comment: I will admit that I don't know F# or C# but I would suggest spending a few days in F# and seeing what you think. To my mind using the REPL is a major win in any language that supports it

Answer (score 5):

Here's what use functional style programming for -- on a more-or-less daily basis.

We do lots of statistical and actuarial things with fairly large datasets.  The data fetched from the database is -- essentially static, immutable objects.  No reason to create a class with methods.

Each stage of the calculation adds some additional details, but doesn't essentially mutate the object.  At the "end" of the pipeline we're really doing a fancy reduce to compute sums and counts and other things.

Imagine this.

```
for data in summarize( enrich( calculate( some_query( criteria() ) ) ) ):
    print data
```

Each "phase" of the calculation is a functional programming loop that does simple read-calculate-yield and creates a composite object of other things plus results.

(We use Python, hence the functional programming using generator functions.)

It's easier to use stateless, immutable objects.

Comment: Does Python have an equivalent to this F#? `criteria() |> some_query |> calculate |> enrich |> summarize` I find the forward pipe operator can lead to clearer code but I digress.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: First, that syntax confuses me.  But some people seem to like it.  There a innumerable Python packages.  I'm sure that you could search for that on SO and find an answer.

Comment: @Chaos: Not that I know of. usually I compose `map` to get the same effect.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, it is not a unique property of a functional programming, and F# is not a pure functional language. F#, as one of ML descendants, provides an excellent pattern matching and algebraic data types. So, for any task which requires complex data structures F# is much more expressive and easy to use than C#.

Imagine implementing a compiler in C# and F# - representing an abstract syntax tree and transforms over it is much simpler if your language provides ADTs and a pattern matching.

Answer (score 2):

Ideal for map-reduce kind of massive multi-system and massive multi-core parallelism. Pretty cool, considering that nowadays entry level servers come with 48 cores (96 counting HT).

Answer (score 2):

If you want fully functional try Haskell, Erlang also has some very cool stuff about it.

Simon Payton-Jones said about Haskell, he wants to have a program that obviously has no bugs, rather than have no obvious bugs.

(I probably got the quote a bit off, but you get the idea)

By constraining side effects you make it much easier to prove your code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

One definite advantage is that it's much more easily parallelised.

Comment: You're talking about purity and one obvious disadvantage is that purity tends to make programs a lot slower. So parallel+pure is not necessarily a good thing.